# Rails API + engine + omniauth + session/flash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise, omniauth, rails-flash

I have a tricky scenario here and I cannot find the solution by myself yet. This is perfectly working in production (no ngrok).

Here is the setup.

- Rails API (6.1.6)
- 2 engines mounted via subdomain

  1. Main API - `MainAPI` -> api.lvh.me:3003
  2. Temp front for users `TempFront` (will be removed in a couple of months). -> temp.lvh.me:3003

On the `TempFront`, I've setup what's missing on a Rails API to be able to have a front available. Everything works fine except omniauth redirection. I've tracked down the error until [WardenManager#call](https://github.com/wardencommunity/warden/blob/master/lib/warden/manager.rb#L30-L48)

After redirection, session is not stored. I've obviously skip the `protect_from_forgery` on callback method based on [FAQ](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#my-rails-session-has-been-wiped-out-in-my-authentication-callback-what-do-i-do-) but it is still not working.

Flash are not shared as well. I thought it might be linked to the same issue. I'm pretty sure it is coming from my custom configuration somewhere but I cannot find exactly where.

Locally I'm using ngrok to have the callback. Url is `api.ngrok.my-domain.com` (which does not match `*.lvh.me` but direct to the correct engine `MainAPI`).

After manual `sign_in(@user, event: :authentication)`, there is a correct session key `warden.user.v1_user.key` with value [user_id]. This is the correct behaviour. This same key disappears after the redirect.

Here is the initializer I've set on `temp_front/lib/temp_front/engine.rb`

```rb
require 'webpacker'

module TempFront
  ##
  # Engine initializers
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace TempFront

    initializer 'webpacker.proxy' do |app|
      insert_middleware =
          begin
            TempFront.webpacker.config.dev_server.present?
          rescue StandardError
            nil
          end
      next unless insert_middleware

      app.middleware.insert_before(
          0, Rails::VERSION::MAJOR >= 5 ?
                 Webpacker::DevServerProxy : 'Webpacker::DevServerProxy',
          ssl_verify_none: true,
          webpacker: TempFront.webpacker
      )
    end

    initializer 'use action cookies and dispatch flash' do |app|
      app.config.session_store :cookie_store, { key: '_my_app', domain: :all }
      app.config.middleware.insert_before(Warden::Manager, ActionDispatch::Cookies)
      app.config.middleware.insert_after(ActionDispatch::Cookies, ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore,
                                     opts)
      app.config.middleware.insert_after(ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore, ActionDispatch::Flash)
      # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-middleware
      # Rack::MethodOverride allows the method to be overridden
      # if params[:_method] is set.
      # This is the middleware which supports
      # the PATCH, PUT, and DELETE HTTP method types.
      app.config.middleware.use Rack::MethodOverride
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my callback controller:

```rb
module MainAPI
  class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

    before_action :some_callbacks_to_handle_data

    def facebook
      sign_in @user, event: :authentication
      flash[:notice] = 'You have done it!'
      redirect_to mod_temp_front_engine.profile_url(subdomain: 'temp')
    end
  end
end
```

Does anybody have another idea to fix that?